# Is the FoldLeft function available in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, list

I would like to know if there is an implementation of the foldLeft function (and foldRight?) in R.

The language is supposed to be "rather" functional oriented and hence I think there should be something like this, but I could not find it in the documentation.

To me, foldLeft function applies on a list and has the following signature:

```
foldLeft[B](z : B)(f : (B, A) => B) : B
```

It is supposed to return the following result:

```
f(... (f(f(z, a0), a1) ...), an) if the list is [a0, a1, ..., an].
```

(I use the definition of the [Scala List API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/List.html#reduceLeft%28%28B%2CA%29%3D%3EB%29))

Does anybody know if such a function exists in R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

?Reduce.
Usage
Reduce(f, x, init, right = FALSE, accumulate = FALSE)

Comment: arf. I knew I had seen it somewhere!
Do you know if there is a package dedicated to list handling with optimal functions? or are they all already implemented in the base package and I did not find them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vector of results, this will work:

```
foldl = function(f, v, x) {w = v; for (i in 1 : length(v)) { x = w[[i]] = f(x, v[[i]]) }; w }
```

Now you can redefine `cumsum` as

```
cumsum(v) = foldl(function(x,y) { x+y }, v, 0)
```

To improve it you should handle missing values like `Reduce` does.