# Reduce left-fold in R

Tags: r, lambda, fold, higher-order-functions

I am using the higher-order function to apply a function to every element in a vector and return the result as a scalar value.

Suppose I have:

```
v = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

I want to compute the sum of all these integers centered 5 integers to the left:

SUM(i-5) for i in v:

```
Reduce(function(i) sum(i-5), v, 0)
```

I get the following error: `Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument(s) (x[[i]])`

What is going wrong with my lambda function?

Thanks!

Comment: I may not understand but can't you just do: `sum(v - 5)`

Comment: Yes, I am looking to generalize this and learn how to use higher order functions though.

Comment: If you have to use `Reduce` (for learning purposes, as clearly this is not the solution to use here): then you should know that it expects 2 arguments. So you should do something like: `Reduce(function(x,y) sum(x-y), list(v, 5))`

Comment: John Myles White gives a nice [tutorial on Higher Order Functions](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/09/23/higher-order-functions-in-r/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the FoldLeft function available in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042435/is-the-foldleft-function-available-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you want (if using `Reduce` - clearly not the right thing to do for this particular case, so this is for demonstration purposes only):

```
Reduce(function(x,y) {x+y-5}, v, 0)
```

This will start at the left of `v`, will add the next element and subtract 5 and will keep doing that until it reaches the end of `v`.

You should be able to see how you can modify to put an arbitrary function of the two elements (the accumulated one and the next one) instead of the one you chose for your question.

Comment: It should be noted here that `x` is the accumulator variable.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the help page for `Reduce`. Specifically,

```
Arguments:

   f: a function of the appropriate arity (binary for ‘Reduce’,
      unary for ‘Filter’, ‘Find’ and ‘Position’, k-ary for ‘Map’ if
      this is called with k arguments).  An arbitrary predicate
      function for ‘Negate’.
```

Your function is a single argument function. `Reduce` wants a two-argument function.